# how do i integrate CSS in javafx project?

Tags: css, javafx

I'm trying to integrate background and button styles in my quiz project.
But I can't reach the CSS.

I have following stylesheet(mainstyle.css):

```
.root{
    -fx-background-image: url("/afbeeldingen/Achtergrond/background_image.jpg");
    -fx-background-repeat:stretch;
    -fx-background-size: 600 1000;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box,black,30,0.5,0,0);
}

.Button {
    -fx-font-size: 48;
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-radius: 10;
    -fx-padding: 5 20 5 20;
}

.choice-box{-fx-background-color: yellow;
}
```

And the following implementation in de Quizapp

```
public class QuizApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Lijst model = new Lijst();
        QuizView view = new QuizView();
        QuizPresenter presenter = new QuizPresenter(model,view);
        Scene scene = new Scene(view);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("mainStyle.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("LANDENQUIZ");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(1000);
        primaryStage.setHeight(600);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

But I can't see a background image or other style...

Comment: Yes, and now I've changed it to mainstyle.css in the code but now I get an other error while I try to run the code: "Exception in Application start method" "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"

Comment: note that there are naming conventions: for Button style, the selector is _.button_ (not .Button) For additional details (like the complete stacktrace, f.i. :) please edit the question and add them there (vs posting snippets as comment). If you want to dig into the error yourself: the important part is around a line like _caused by_